# How to access the device selection menu?

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, mediarecorder

I want to know if I can access the menu of devices from HTML5 / JavaScript (the menu that I show on the pictures).

[Menu in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jHRp.png)

I do't want something like this: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices).

First you need to request permission for access using `navigator.GetUserMedia`, which may still have browser-specific implementations.

You could then use `enumerateDevices` in the success callback, and populate some listboxes (etc) from there.

Here's something that works in webkit browsers (e.g. Chrome). You should use modernizr, or check for each browser-specific implementation of `GetUserMedia`.

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
{ audio: true, video: true }, 
function(MediaStream){
    // success
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        .then(function(devices){
            devices.forEach(function(device){
                console.log(device);
            });
        });
}, 
function(){
    // error
}
);
```